How can I define a LaTeX environment to capture and discard content without printing it?
I'm working with an existing LaTeX library, and I need to modify an environment so that its content is captured, discarded and not printed. The goal is to do it without introducing external packages like environ, as modifying the library code is challenging.
Here’s the current definition of the environment I’m working with:
\newenvironment{task}[1][]%
{%
  \stepcounter{alltasks}% Increment counters
  \@task{#1}% Process metadata
  \let\do@nothing\relax % A no-op macro to discard the content
  \long\def\do@nothing##1{}%
  \do@nothing
}
{%
  \smallskip
}

And here’s how I’m using it:
\begin{tasklist}
  \begin{task}[id=wa:mbr:tst:t1,wphases={0-3!0.6666666666666666666666}]
    Nonlocal fitting
  \end{task}
  \begin{task}[id=wa:mbr:tst:t2,wphases={3-6}]
    Another task content
  \end{task}
\end{tasklist}

Currently, even though the content (Nonlocal fitting, Another task content) is passed through \do@nothing, it still gets printed in the output document. I want to capture and discard the body of the task environment so it is not printed in the final document.

Hope you expect, \begin{comment}...\end{comment} from the package comment.sty

You probably should have a look at the output-routine. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/output-routine?sort=MostVotes&edited=true

Again you've unfortunately not posted a minimal working example as recommended. So there is nothing I could use to test. Maybe you can try something like \NewDocumentEnvironment{task}{o+b}{}{}. See the usrguide for more information about \NewDocumentEnvironment and Body of an environment.
